# What's the best way to override a default key binding in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I'm using spacemacs: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs

I've tried both user hook places for overriding cmd-k to be `kill-buffer` rather than `delete-window`. However, when I restart, neither works.

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()
  "Initialization function for user code.
It is called immediately after `dotspacemacs/init'.  You are free to put any
user code."
  (defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()
    (global-set-key (kbd "s-k") 'kill-buffer)
    )
  )

(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration function for user code.
 This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs initialization after
layers configuration. You are free to put any user code."
    (global-set-key (kbd "s-k") 'kill-buffer)
)
```

What's the best way to debug this?

Comment: What's the command bind to "s-k" after restart your Emacs? Maybe the keybindings are override by other layers or minor mode

Comment: I suspect it's the mac os bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that you have defined `defun dotspacemacs/user-init` inside `defun dotspacemacs/user-init`.

Rather than that, I test `(global-set-key (kbd "s-k") 'kill-buffer)` in `dotspacemacs/user-init` and `dotspacemacs/user-config` and works it both places.

Maybe the error it's something related to your config file.

Did you have enabled osx layer?

Comment: I probably have enabled the osx layer. Here's my setup: https://github.com/justin808/justin808-dotfiles/tree/master/jg-spacemacs